# Rename axes in plotly 3d hover text

Tags: python, plotly

I'm drawing a picture in 3D with plot.ly and I want my axes to be referenced as `(t, x, y)` instead of `(x, y, z)`. It is possible to give them different titles (under `Scene` object in case of 3D), but when I hover on the plot, I get a tooltip that ignores new titles and still uses `(x, y, z)`. Is it possible to rename them too?

My code is

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter3d, Layout, Scene
from numpy import sin, cos, linspace, pi
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode()

t = linspace(0, 4*pi)

trace = Scatter3d(
    x = t,
    y = cos(t),
    z = sin(t),
    mode = 'lines'
)
layout = Layout(
                width = 500, 
                height = 500, 
                scene = Scene(
                    xaxis = {'title': 't'},
                    yaxis = {'title': 'x'},
                    zaxis = {'title': 'y'}
                )
)
iplot(dict(data=[trace], layout=layout))
```

When I hover on graph, I have:

[image: tooltip]

And I want to change `x, y, z` here to `t, x, y` or anything else.

Comment: Filling this as planned enhancement. Thanks for the report. Please subscribe to https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/265 for the latest development information.

Comment: @etpinard, okay, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more workaround than solution, but you could define a list of strings, one item for each point on your line, where each item in the list is a string of whatever text you wanted to show when hovering (including the string `"<br>"` for a line return), then set `text=your_list` and `hoverinfo="text"`.

Like this:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter3d, Layout, Scene
from numpy import sin, cos, linspace, pi
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode()
t = linspace(0, 4*pi)
your_list=[]
for iter_t in t:
    iter_string = 't:'+'%1.3f'%iter_t+'<br>' + 'x:'+'%1.3f'%cos(iter_t) + '<br>'+'y:'+'%1.3f'%sin(iter_t)
    your_list.append(iter_string)

trace = Scatter3d(
    x = t,
    y = cos(t),
    z = sin(t),
    mode = 'lines',
    text=your_list,
    hoverinfo='text')

layout = Layout(width = 500, height = 500, scene = Scene(
    xaxis = {'title': 't'},
    yaxis = {'title': 'x'},
    zaxis = {'title': 'y'}))

iplot(dict(data=[trace], layout=layout))
```

Resulting plot looks like this

[image]

You should probably be saving the computed values in the for loop in order to prevent having to compute them more than once, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be possible solution; could you please provide code example?