# Change axis name in box plotly python

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

How to change axis name in box like the following picture from R documentation?

[image]

Simple renaming doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add a minimal, verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and what you tried so far?

Comment: solved, code that was needed here https://plot.ly/python/2d-projection-of-3d-surface/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docs : https://plot.ly/python/2d-projection-of-3d-surface/
You could define a list of strings, one item for each point on your surface where each item in the list is a string of whatever text you wanted to show when hovering (including the string "
" for a line return), then set text=your_list and hoverinfo="text".

```
textz=[['x: '+'{:0.5f}'.format(x[i][j])+'<br>y: '+'{:0.5f}'.format(y[i][j])+
    '<br>z: '+'{:0.5f}'.format(z[i][j]) for j in range(z.shape[1])] for i in range(z.shape[0])]

trace1= Surface(z=z,
            x=x,
            y=y, 
            colorscale=colorscale,
            text=textz,
            hoverinfo='text',
            )
```

Comment: for python scatter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467316/rename-axes-in-plotly-3d-hover-text
js surface : http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/RGJpoO